# Azure application Insights query for monitoring trend comparison

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-application-insights, health-monitoring, azure-monitoring

I am looking for comparing diffrent trends in Azure App Insights , Chart looks like below

[image]

Can we have any example query's to compare multiple events in the same chart ? Can someone help getting an example query or reference documents in Azure Application Insights ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Workbooks or in the Log Analytics query window with something like this:

```
customEvents
| summarize count() by name, bin(timestamp, 7d)
```

[image]

[image]

For AppInsights customEvent data the above query would work, if it is a more traditional Azure Monitor/Log Analytics event then you would need a different query as the tables/field names are different.

Log Analytics uses TimeGenerated whereas classic App Insights resources use Timestamp.